# How do I make python selenium webdriver type text and fill one name element over the other

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Essentially I'm trying to fill a text box, but it keeps filling the wrong one. I've tried driver.find_element_by_name but it goes to the one at the bottom of the page instead of the one that it needs to fill at the top. This is for a Checkout page and it needs to fill out the Email address text box but it goes to the bottom and fills out the signup for newsletter text box. I have tried xpath,id, and class but none of those work.

[(1)Html code that I need to fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQVPH.png)

[(2)Html code that I don't want to fill but fills instead of 1st html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw94k.png)

Comment: Please show script you had tried so far.

Comment: Like just the commands I’ve used or my code rn?

Comment: Your python selenium code